# Load fragment after Delay on Main Thread

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have a NavigationDrawer which is a left side menu, when i touch a button in this button i load a new fragment like this :

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,""+tagFragment).commit(); 
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

I have a fragment which use a camera instance, the fragment is slower to load than the other fragment, if i load the camera fragment like the other the app freeze for a slow time so i want to add a progress Bar on my main activity and when the camera fragment is loaded i use a callback to remove the progressView.

to do so i show the progress Bar and load the fragment after a delay :

```
RelativeLayout layoutLoadingIndicator = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_loading_indicator); 
                    layoutLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Handler mainHandler = new Handler(this.getMainLooper()); 

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                          .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,""+tagFragment).commit(); 
                          fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();                         }
                    };

worker.schedule(task, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The camera fragment is loaded after 2 seconds, works fine. 
The problem is that when i want to load a new fragment it's still the camera fragment that is on the screen the fragment is replace below the camera fragment.
If i remove the Runnable task and that i load the camera fragment like the other there is no problem i can switch to other fragment.

I supposed that the problem come from the Runnable task and the fragment manager.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncTask` might solve your problem.

For example in my app I am using `AsyncTask` when I am communicating with server for login purposes. I can show you part of my code as an example:

```
    public static void login(final Context c, final String username, final String password, final String apiUrl, final ILoginHandler handler) {
            UserName = username;
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                SecureDataClient dataClient;
                public String getLocalIpAddress() {
                    try {
                        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                                    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                                    Log.e(TAG, "***** IP="+ ip);
                                    return ip;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SocketException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    dataClient = new SecureDataClient(username, password,apiUrl);
                    try {
                        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
                        request.put("function", "GetNearestDataServer");
                        request.put("deviceIpAddress", getLocalIpAddress());
                        JSONObject response = dataClient.createRetriever().executeJSON(request);
                        if (response != null) {
                            dataClient.setApiLocation(response.getString("url"));
                            UserDataClient = dataClient;
                            BaseApp.devicesList = Devices.GetDevices(dataClient);
                            BaseApp.device = Devices.GetDevice(dataClient);
                            request = new JSONObject();
                            request.put("function", "GetServerActualTime");
                            response = dataClient.createRetriever().executeJSON(request);
                            if (response != null) {
                                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatters.ISO8601();
                                DateTime userTime = DateTime.now(zone());
                                DateTime serverTime = fmt.parseDateTime(response.getString("server_actual_time"));
                               /* if(user == null)
                                {
                                    user = new User(c,null);
                                }
                                user.timeOffset = Seconds.secondsBetween(userTime, serverTime).getSeconds();*/
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Login error", e);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
}
```

As you can see there `AsynTask` ha a method `doInBackground` wich does its stuff in background. In this example I have `Asynctask` communicating with server in background progress bar is shown to user. Hope I explained it well enough, since english is not my first language.